# How to pass Bearer Token in web service consumer component in mule 4?

Tags: soap, mule

I need to pass the Bearer Token to a downstream system (connected using webservice consumer component) in below format.

```
Bearer [token value]
```

I tried passing it inline header with key: Bearer and Value= token value but it did not work. 
I tried to pass the XML below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
 ---
headers : {
   Authorization: {
    "Bearer " ++ vars.licenseServerTocken
}
}
```

but got the error below:

```
"Error trying to acquire a new connection:Error fetching the resource [https://abc123.com/xyz/Contract.svc?wsdl]: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://abc123.com/xyz/Contract.svc?wsdl"
```

It is working from SOAP UI when I pass as below in body

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tem.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <Authorization>Bearer sada3123gjkada1231</Authorization>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The Authorization header is not part of the SOAP request, nor SOAP headers. It is part of the HTTP request that is the transport of the SOAP request. So you need to define in the transport headers section.

Example:

```
    <wsc:consume doc:name="Consume" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" operation="MyService">
        <wsc:message >
            <wsc:body > ... </wsc:body>
        </wsc:message>
        <wsc:transport-headers >
            <wsc:transport-header key="Authorization" value="#['Bearer ' ++  vars.licenseServerTocken ]" />
        </wsc:transport-headers>
    </wsc:consume>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoting for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is Authorization token. You pass it like this

Authorization: Bearer token

Example of key:value in the header

Authorization: Bearer fc654rrhfdc643q6ecyi6uo6thvg

Comment: Hi Alex - where should i pass ? I tried passing in header but it throws invalid input

Comment: I added example - you have to pass header value of the Authorization as "Bearer 98687687687687697" where this 98687687687687697 is your token